# Extracting Test outcomes serenity BDD

Tags: maven, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Went through the serenity documented for extracting the test outcomes
below isthe code, it didn't work

> OutcomeFormat format = OutcomeFormat.XML; TestOutcomes outcomes =
>   TestOutcomeLoader.loadTestOutcomes().inFormat(format)

Tried with below code and its working,

> OutcomeFormat format = OutcomeFormat.JSON;     TestOutcomeLoaderBuilder
>   outcomes= TestOutcomeLoader.loadTestOutcomes().inFormat(format);
>   TestOutcomes out =outcomes.from(new File(""));

Issue is i need the test outcomes in @AfterScenario, but the thing is serenity reports gets generated after the entire execution tried changing the pom but didn't help. Is there any other way using which we can extract the test results?

Answer (score 0):

Serenity uses JSON format by default now. Why are you trying to obtain the test outcomes? (i.e. what problem are you trying to solve?)

Comment: I want to extract the test cases(Entire GWT with example) and test results for uploading it to rally.

Answer (score 0):

Created a separate java class for report extracting and added that in maven plugin which will get executed after serenity report is generated.

Answer (score 0):

As @John smart has mentioned JSON and HTML are default output formats.

Still if you want to access Outcomes after test execution.
You can create a custom listener and listen to serenity event bus.
TestRunFinished event will be published with Outcome as a parameter.
You can use the outcome for getting required details.

For creating custom listener you can follow this [page](https://schenkweb.nl/2017/07/11/serenity-bdd-register-a-custom-listener/)